# Can't run digest() on PosrgreSQL 9.3 on RDS

Tags: postgresql-9.3, hashing

Following [the advice given on another answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81175/compare-table-content-from-different-postgresql-9-3-dbs), I tried using the [`digest()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/pgcrypto.html) function on PostgreSQL 9.3 on AWS RDS:

```
devdb=> SELECT digest('blah', 'sha1');
ERROR:  function digest(unknown, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT digest('blah', 'sha1');
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Even though pgcrypto exist:

```
devdb=> SHOW rds.extensions;
```

> btree_gin,btree_gist,chkpass,citext,cube,dblink,dict_int,dict_xsyn,earthdistance,fuzzystrmatch,hstore,intagg,intarray,isn,ltree,pgcrypto,pgrowlocks,pg_trgm,plperl,plpgsql,pltcl,postgis,postgis_tiger_geocoder,postgis_topology,sslinfo,tablefunc,tsearch2,unaccent,uuid-ossp

How can I enable the `digest()` function?

### Updates

I have [co-asked on the AWS RDS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=164142), will posts mutually updated.

`digest()` does not seem to exist on the db:

```
devdb=> \df digest
                       List of functions
 Schema | Name | Result data type | Argument data types | Type
--------+------+------------------+---------------------+------
(0 rows)
```

Comment: Output of `\df digest` in `psql`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The question was answered at the AWS forum by [Shawn@AWS](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/profile.jspa?userID=257889) - **The `rds.extension` list shows available, rather than installed, modules.**

> Thank you for using RDS Postgres. The "rds.extension" parameter shows you what extensions are available in RDS Postgres. You still need to execute the "create extension" command.
>
> Using your test case:

```
postgres=> show rds.extensions;
... ,pgcrypto, ...
postgres=> create extension pgcrypto;
CREATE EXTENSION

postgres=> SELECT digest('blah', 'sha1');
digest
\x5bf1fd927dfb8679496a2e6cf00cbe50c1c87145
(1 row)
```

### Addendum

`pg_available_extensions` shows which extensions are available and which are already installed:

```
postgres=> SELECT * FROM pg_available_extensions;

          name          | default_version | installed_version |                               comment
------------------------+-----------------+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------
 chkpass                | 1.0             |                   | data type for auto-encrypted passwords
 xml2                   | 1.0             |                   | XPath querying and XSLT
 plpgsql                | 1.0             | 1.0               | PL/pgSQL procedural language
 pgcrypto               | 1.0             |                   | cryptographic functions
 postgres_fdw           | 1.0             |                   | foreign-data wrapper for remote PostgreSQL servers
...
```

Comment: **Addendum Addendum**: Extensions have to be created once per database. And the `pgcrypto` extension is special as it can only be created by the database superuser (normally `postgres`). With peer auth enabled as usual on Ubuntu etc., the following command would bring you to the correct prompt to create the extension: `sudo -u postgres psql -U postgres -d database_name`

Answer (score 0):

1. `sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib-9.1` or depending on your postgres version (Check [debian pkg](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=pgcrypto.control&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=any) or depending on your distrib)
2. in postgres: `CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;`